# Pandas: how do you map a dictionary of dictionaries to 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
rates = {'USD': 
              {'2019': 1,
               '2020': 2,
               '2021': 3},
         'CAD':
              {'2019': 4,
               '2020': 5,
               '2021': 6}
         }
```

and I have the following dummy dataframe:

```
   Item Currency Year Rate
0  1    USD      2019 
1  2    USD      2020
2  3    CAD      2021
3  4    CAD      2019
4  5    GBP      2020
```

I now want to populate the column `Rate` by mapping the correct rate, where `rate = f(currency,year)`. I am trying with:

```
def map_rate(data, rates):

    for index, row in data.iterrows():

        currency = str(row['Currency'])

        if currency in list(rates.keys()):

            year = str(row['Year'])
            rate = rates[currency][year]

        else:
            rate = 1

    return rate
```

I use the above like the following:

```
df['Rate'] = map_rate(test, rates)
```

However, this is only returning the first rate, e.g. the value 1, instead of the appropriate rates:

```
    Item Currency Year  Rate
0   1    USD      2019  1
1   2    USD      2020  1
2   3    CAD      2021  1
3   4    CAD      2019  1
4   5    GBP      2020  1
```

The expected result is:

```
    Item Currency Year  Rate
0   1    USD      2019  1
1   2    USD      2020  2
2   3    CAD      2021  6
3   4    CAD      2019  4
4   5    GBP      2020  1
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Side note: you can directly check against the dictionary whether a key exists or not: `if currency in rates` instead of `if currency in list(rates.keys())`. Latter forms a list and loses ~O(1) lookup time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, create a multiindex series from rates with `stack`, that you can `reindex` with the values from df to get the wanted rate per row.

```
df['rate'] = (
    pd.DataFrame(rates)
      .stack()
      .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['Year','Currency']].astype(str)), 
               fill_value=1)
     .to_numpy()
)
print(df)
   Item Currency  Year  rate
0     1      USD  2019     1
1     2      USD  2020     2
2     3      CAD  2021     6
3     4      CAD  2019     4
4     5      GBP  2020     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `.apply`

**Ex:**

```
df['Rate'] = df.apply(lambda x: rates[x['Currency']][x['Year']], axis=1)
# OR
df['Rate'] = df.apply(lambda x: rates.get(x['Currency'], dict()).get(x['Year'], 1), axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Item Currency  Year  Rate
0    1      USD  2019     1
1    2      USD  2020     2
2    3      CAD  2021     6
3    4      CAD  2019     4
4    5      GBP  2020     1
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you think my solution does not work?

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working....its probably because `if currency in list(rates.keys()):` fails

Comment: I still get the value of `1` even if I remove the condition. It seems like it's not properly looping over the different currency names.

Comment: @Zizzipupp it is because your function return a scalar (and in this case 1 because it is the last value obtained in the loop) while you should return a list of values, one for each iteration

Comment: You probably have bad data. check if it has leading space?

Answer (score 2):

Create another dataframe for rates

```
rates_df = pd.DataFrame(rates).unstack().reset_index()
rates_df.columns = ['Currency', 'Year', 'Rates']
rates_df['Year'] = rates_df['Year'].astype(int)
```

Then merge

```
df.merge(rates_df, on=['Currency', 'Year'], how='left').fillna(1)
```

Rates Dataframe

```
  Currency  Year  Rates
0      USD  2019      1
1      USD  2020      2
2      USD  2021      3
3      CAD  2019      4
4      CAD  2020      5
5      CAD  2021      6
```

Output

```
   Item Currency  Year  Rates
0     1      USD  2019    1.0
1     2      USD  2020    2.0
2     3      CAD  2021    6.0
3     4      CAD  2019    4.0
4     5      GBP  2020    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with the built-in Pandas method `df.apply()`. Here's a more verbose example than the other posted answers.

**Code:**

```
def get_rate(row):
  if row['Currency'] in rates.keys():
    return rates[row['Currency']][row['Year']]
  else:
    return 1

df['Rate'] = df.apply(get_rate,axis=1)

print(df)
```